# Catch the event when the user selected a permission in google_maps_flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

When the map is built for the first time

```dart
GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition: _startPosition,
  myLocationEnabled: true,
);
```

the system asks for permission

[image: 1]

How can I catch the moment when the user has made a choice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasPermission` method of location class using [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) plugin. From this you can catch the moment.
please look at below :-

```
final _hasLocationPermission = await location.hasPermission();
      if (_hasLocationPermission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        //Code here
      } else if (_hasLocationPermission == PermissionStatus.denied) {
        final _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
        if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.granted) {
         //Code here
        } else if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
          //Code here
        }
      }
```

Comment: But you have given only the function for handling the result. A result handling is not a problem. I need to find an event into which I can insert this handling.